# How to dump (write) IStream's content into file (Image)

Tags: c++, c, istream

I have an [IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I know it contains a PNG file, but I can't write its content into a file like normal I/O stream, I don't know if I am doing something wrong or I should do a different thing for writing [IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into file.

```
    IStream *imageStream;
    std::wstring imageName;
    packager.ReadPackage(imageStream, &imageName);      

    std::ofstream test("mypic.png");
    test<< imageStream;
```

Comment: You need to use the binary writing methods for image data. `<<` will corrupt the file in certain systems. Try `std::ofstream test("mypic.png", std::ios::binary); test.write(...);` I don't know how IStream() works to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the `IStream` reference you gave here is some **untested** code that should do roughly what you want:

```
void output_image(IStream* imageStream, const std::string& file_name)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(file_name, std::ios::binary); // binary mode!!

    char buffer[1024]; // temporary transfer buffer

    ULONG pcbRead; // number of bytes actually read

    // keep going as long as read was successful and we have data to write
    while(imageStream->Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &pcbRead) == S_OK && pcbRead > 0)
    {
        ofs.write(buffer, pcbRead);
    }

    ofs.close();
}
```